# iText 7 - put values of variables into the text of pdf

Tags: java, itext, itext7

Is there any possible ways of adding something like labels or variables onto the PDF file?

I'm doing welcome page from template pdf via iText 7 on Java and I'm stuck with personalizing it.

I want to `login` and `password` be changable values

```
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter("source.pdf");
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    document.add(new Paragraph("Thank you for registration, Dear " + login + "!"));
    document.add(new Paragraph("That is your password: " + pass)
    document.close();
```

,where `login` and `pass` are assigned to "_____"

Here the pseudocode of how I change the actual values of login and password and create new PDF file

```
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("source.pdf"), new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    login = inputtedLogin; // pseudocode
    pass = inputtedPass;  // pseudocode
    Print text;          // pseudocode

    document.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact usecase.
But you may want to have a look at pdf forms.
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-filling-out-forms

Essentially, this allows you to;

- create a document once (with forms)
- load the document
- Fill in the form fields
- Flatten the document (to remove the interactivity)

Comment: thanks, I think that is what I need. But I've a question about form.getField("Name"). Name is the name of the field or what? If yes, how to declare these fields?

Comment: It turns out that it is wrong or it is problem with me. since I need to change only the values of certain words

Comment: above link is not valid now, use this -> https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/filling-out-forms